# Necesito Ayuda ¿Como agregar Spinner a una función que recorre la tabla para exportar datos en excel? Angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner

Necesito agregar spinner y quitarlo cuando termine de ejecutar la función "exportTable" Como se muestra en el ejemplo:

**ts:**

```
  Export(){
    this.spinner.show();
    this.ExpTable.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'Cat_claves_presup', sheet: 'Hoja1', Props: {Author: 'Administrador'}});
    this.spinner.hide();
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-button (click)="Export()">
          <mat-icon color="primary">unarchive</mat-icon>Exportar
        </button>
        <button mat-button>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrar por">
          </mat-form-field>
        </button>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <div>
      <mat-table matTableExporter  #exporter="matTableExporter" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="overflow-x: scroll !important; display: grid" class="scroll" hiddenColumns="[1,3,4]">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id_clav_p">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="columna1"> No. </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="columna1" > {{row.id_clav_p}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

La problemática es que no se muestra el Spinner y se ejecuta la función la cual recorre el mat-table para exportar los datos

Comment: Creo que no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, amigo. ¿Podrías agregar más detalles a tu post? ¿Qué has intentando? ¿Cuáles son los resultados que has obtenido?¿Y cuál es el resultado que esperabas? ¿Te muestra algún error?...

Comment: La problemática es que no se muestra el Spinner (<mat-progress-spinner>) es decir el componente que muestra la espera del proceso y simplemente ejecuta la función la cual recorre el mat-table para exportar los datos. he intentado agregar callbacks, subscribe y hasta setTimeout pero no consigo que primero muestre el spinner luego ejecute el codigo que exporta y finalmente oculte el spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero declarar una variable privada Tipo Boleano que valide tu carga por ejemplo:

```
 Export(){
this.varSpinner= true;
this.ExpTable.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'Cat_claves_presup', sheet: 'Hoja1', Props: {Author: 'Administrador'}});
this.varSpinner = false;}
```

y puedes utilizar del lado de HTML el Icono de Fa-spinner algo como esto quedaría:

```
 <button mat-button (click)="Export()" [disabled]="varSpinner">
      <mat-icon color="primary">unarchive</mat-icon>Exportar
      <i [ngClass]="{'fa-spinner fa-spin': varSpinner}" class="fa"></i>
    </button>
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrar por">
      </mat-form-field>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <div>
  <mat-table matTableExporter  #exporter="matTableExporter" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="overflow-x: scroll !important; display: grid" class="scroll" hiddenColumns="[1,3,4]">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id_clav_p">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="columna1"> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="columna1" > {{row.id_clav_p}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Agregué la directiva [disable], para que desactive tu botón de exportación mientras se carga el reporte, para evitar que el usuario bombardee el botón y la [ngClass] te permitirá ver lo del spinner que buscas. Espero te sirva.

Nota: cabe mencionar que tu variable privada "varSpinner" debes declararla como False:

```
private varSpinner = false;
```